# What parts do I have to change if I want to change my derailleur to higher speed?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear

I want to change my derailleur from a Tourney TY-300 to an Altus M2000. What bike parts do I need to change? I want to change my derailleur because i mostly ride forest trails and I have heard the new m2000,3000,4000 are for mtb bike.i have a big buck bike 
And I wanted to upgrade the derailleur because my derailleur got bent a little bit because of an accident and after sometime it got more bent because of me riding trails so that why I want to change it and because the derailleur doesn’t shift good and the bike mechanic shop near me said there is no fix for this derailleur and that he Could only adjust it and that fix would only be temporary.so I have to choose between getting a new ty-300 derailleur or upgrading to an actual mtb derailleur

Comment: Welcome to the site, remember to check out the [tour]. Do you mean you want to change from 7 speed to 9 speed? You could [edit] that detail in. Also what kind of handlebars and shifters do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to upgrade from a Tourney 7 speed group component to an Altus M2000 is 9 speed.

You'd obviously have to change the rear derailleur, shifters, rear sprocket cluster and chain.  Presumably you have 3 chainring crank, Altus M2000 comes in a 3x9 option. You'd have to swap the front derailleur but you might be able to keep the crankset.

However, you need to look at your rear wheel. If you have an old style *freewheel* (sprockets and pawls mechanism in a single unit) you can't upgrade it to 9 speed. If you have a *freehub* and sprocket *cassette* (ratchet mechanism is part of the hub), you may be able to upgrade to 9 speeds. The freehub body for 7 speeds and below is narrower than those for 8 and above. If you have a 7 speed freehub, you can't upgrade to 9 speeds. If you happen to have an 8+ freehub with a 7 speed cassette and spacer you will be able to. If your rear wheel isn't compatible, you'd need a new one that is.

If you have to swap out the whole drivetrain, crank and rear wheel it's probably just not worth doing the upgrade, especially when you factori in the cost of having a bike repair shop do it for you, or the cost of special tools you'd need to do it yourself.

Comment: I'd expect the existing front mech should be okay, and doesn't need changing.  It may benefit from being pinched closed a little around the new thinner chain, but I've successfully used a 7 speed FD on a 9 speed.

Comment: The question has now been edited to say that the asker is replacing the derailleur because it was damaged. It seems they just want to install a nicer derailleur, not upgrade the whole groupset (despite them accepting your answer).

Comment: Exactly thank you for this comment David Richerby

Answer (score 1):

Shimano derailleurs thru 9 speed will work correctly with any Shimano 7, 8, 9 speed shifter and, therefore, the RD-M2000 would work in this situation.

Based on your situation of damage to your rear derailleur, you must be sure your derailleur hanger--the piece where your derailleur attaches to the bike frame-- is in proper alignment.  Not bent or damaged.  I'll defer to your bike shop guy, as that is one aspect of derailleur "adjustment" and perhaps what he is referring to.

Again, based on your brief sketch of your riding style, perhaps upgrading to a newer mountain bike would be a good investment. As Argenti's answer, describes, there's quite a bit of componentry to switch out if you'd like more of an  upgrade with increased speeds.  I'm not sure what a "big buck bike" is, but your local bike shop should let you test ride their selection.  A quality, entry-level mountain bike will come stock with M2000-3000-4000 components at a very reasonable price.  You'll gain wider-range of gearing, modern geometry of the frame, brake options that include disc brakes, and a variety of suspension options.

Comment: A big buck bike is a cheap bike you can get with cheap components and when someone gets these kind of bike they intend to upgrade it after time.if you live in USA then a big buck bike is the bikes sold in Walmart

Comment: Correct on Shimano MTB 7-9 speed, wrong on SRAM. Shimano classic actuation ratio is 1:1.7 , SRAM '1:1' is actually 1:1.1. https://www.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/.

Comment: I've edited out the erroneous part regarding SRAM -Shimano mixing. Lotsa finer details to keep straight  and I've obviously got a ways to go. Anyway, I'm the type of person who typically wouldn't dream of mixing a set up if at all possible, so opening up the suggestion to others I find quirky. :-)